# Error 2013 in MySQL Workbench when I perform any operation on a certain table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

when using mysql workbench I perform any operation on the table "my_table" I get an error:

```
Error Code: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Previously I stopped the execution of a restore dump and the log showed the message:

```
"the table may be in an inconsistent state"
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: try mysqlcheck <DATABASE>. For more informations see https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/repairing-mysql-databases-and-tables

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query

Comment: partially restored tables will definitely be in a inconsistent state. Rerun the restore and let it complete

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because. The solution is obvious, if you kill a restore, at least one table will be left in an inconsistent state.

Comment: How fast does the error come back?  Immediately?  Or minutes later?

Answer (score 1):

If you kill a restore mid flow, then it is very likely you will leave a table in an inconsistent state.

The first thing you should try is to rerun the restore and allow it to complete.